Why are TCP connections of my own virtualbox process excluded when `lsof`is used without root permissions?
given, virtualboxvm is a process owned by my user, I'd expect the TCP connections of the virtualbox process to be displayed if I use lsof.
Consider the following example - given my username is eddy:
$sudo lsof -n -a -i -ueddy`
COMMAND   PID   USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME 
...
VirtualBo 25679 eddy  95u  IPv4 315623      0t0  TCP  192.168.` ... etc.
...

Why is the above connection not displayed when I use lsof -n -a -i -ueddy w/o sudo?

It belongs to a privileged executable – even though it is currently running with your UID/EUID, the actual /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBoxVM file has the 'setuid' bit set, meaning that it originally starts with its 'effective' EUID being set to someone else (owner of the file, 'root' in most cases), and due to it being privileged you are not allowed to inspect it.
Even if it later drops its effective privileges, the system assumes that the process may still have sensitive information in memory and keeps it protected (or "not dumpable" as it also won't produce memory dumps on crash).
(For example, sudo is likewise a setuid program; its processes initially belong to you but have root as their EUID, so you're not allowed to inspect what it does, e.g. if it reads passwords from /etc/shadow you cannot extract them with a debugger.)

awesome!!! thank you!
